# .NET MVC5 EF Code first inheritance razor issue

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, razor

I am working on a small app to store and display fees.

The app is fairly simple with Members hasmany Fees. Fees can also have FeeTypes.

I am having an issue with displaying associated records via razor syntax.

I need to display the FeeTypeName based on the FeeTypesId in the Fees table but I seem to be hitting a wall. The foreign key is FeeTypesId and corresponds to the PK Id on FeeTypes.

Am I going about this all wrong? I don't want to query every record as Fees already stores the Id just fine.
Models:

```
public class Members
{
    [Key]
    public int MemberNo { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Middle Name")]
    public string MiddleName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Surname")]
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "Invalid Email Address")]
    [Display(Name = "Primary Contact Email")]
    public string MemberPrimaryContactEmail { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Member Status")]
    public MemberStatus MemberStatus { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Member Fees")]
    public virtual ICollection<Fees> Fees { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Member FUM")]
    public float? MemberFUM { get; set; }
    public string MemberWCName { get; set; }
    public string MemberAdviceOSName { get; set; }
    public string MemberRevexName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Accounting Firm")]
    public virtual Accountants AccountantNo { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Adviser Name")]
    public virtual Adviser Adviser { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Head Company")]
    public virtual HeadCompany HeadCompany { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Created_Date { get; set; }
    public string Created_By { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified_Date { get; set; }
    public string Modified_By { get; set; }



}    




public class Fees
{
    [Key]
    public int FeeNo { get; set; }
    public FeeTypes FeeType { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fee Type")]
    public int FeeTypesId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Frequency of Fee")]
    public FeeOccurence FeeOccurence { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fee Amount")]
    public float FeeAmount { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fee Status")]
    public FeeStatus FeeStatus { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Date received (for billing)")]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime? FeeDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Members Members { get; set; }
    public int MemberNo { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Created_Date { get; set; }
    public string Created_By { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified_Date { get; set; }
    public string Modified_By { get; set; }

}

public class FeeTypes
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Fee Name")]
    public string FeeTypeName { get; set; }



}
```

Controller - Where I am trying to display FeeTypeName

```
    public ActionResult Details(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        Members members = db.Members.Find(id);
        ViewBag.Fees = db.Fees.Where(x => x.Members.MemberNo.Equals(x.MemberNo));
        ViewBag.FeeTypesId = new SelectList(db.FeeTypes, "Id", "FeeTypeName");


        if (members == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(members);
    }
```

And the view

```
    @model AccPortal.Models.Members

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    }
                @{ int i = 0; }
                @foreach (var item in Model.Fees)
                {


                    <tr data-id="@i">
                        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Fees.ElementAt(i).FeeNo, new { @class = "md-fee-value", name = "md-fee-id", data_type = "testid", id = "testid" })
                        <td class="md-fee-value" data-type="date">@String.Format("{0:d}", item.FeeDate)</td>
                        <td class="md-fee-value" data-type="type">@item.FeeOccurence</td>
//NEED TO DISPLAY FeeTypeName here instead of FeeTypesId
                        <td class="md-fee-value" data-type="type">@item.FeeTypesId</td>
                        <td class="md-fee-value" data-type="status">@item.FeeStatus</td>
                        <td class="md-fee-value" data-type="amount">@item.FeeAmount</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="md-button md-button--edit" title="edit">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button>
                            <button type="button" class="md-button md-button--remove" title="remove">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    i++;
                }
```

Comment: `"but I seem to be hitting a wall"` - What wall?  In what way does this not work?

Comment: Sorry I was still editing. 
So I can easily display FeeTypesId (because it's stored in Fees) however the corresponding FeeTypeName is what I need to display in the view.

Ive added a comment in the view to show where I mean. "//NEED TO DISPLAY FeeTypeName here instead of FeeTypesId"

Comment: Wouldn't that just be `item.FeeType.FeeTypeName` ?

Comment: Ha, you'd think so, right? Unfortunately I get a null object error. 
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The FeeType is null however FeeTypesId is populated fine.

Comment: Is that property populated in the controller before going to the view?  If not then it seems that you're focusing in the wrong place.  This would be more of an Entity Framework question and less of a Razor or even ASP.NET MVC question.  Could probably be simplified to remove all of that.  (As I'm writing this, an answer is posted below which might in fact be the issue at hand.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the `Fees` model by marking the property as `virtual`:

```
public virtual FeeTypes FeeType { get; set; }
```

Include the `FeeType` when retrieving data:

```
ViewBag.Fees = db.Fees
    .Include(x => x.FeeTypes)
    .Where(x => x.Members.MemberNo.Equals(x.MemberNo));
```

Display it:

```
<td class="md-fee-value" data-type="type">@item.FeeTypes.Name</td>
```

Comment: This was it! Thank you. I am terrible at linq.